# Cannot open Lotus Domino Designer Database

Tags: ibm-domino

I've been given access to `IBM Domino Administrator` through RDP. I need to write some LotusScript for my migration project.

Now, when i can open `IBM Domino Designer`, and when i select some database - there is no reaction to "Open" button. That means, whenever i click "Open" button nothing is happening.
To clarify: i wont open **any** database - Local and remote.

Why is there no error message or anything? Could this be a permission issue?

> IBM Domino Designer 9.0
> Social Edition
> Release 9.0.1
> same version for Domino Administrator

[image: IBM Domino Designer]

If thats the permission issue, how can i grant myself an access?
[image]

[Update] Whenether i try to start the designer from the IBM Domino Administrator - nothing happens either - only nupdate.exe shows up in taskmgr.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.

You normally have 3 clients (Admin, Designer and Notes)

1. Close all your opened client exept the Notes client
2. Go in the Notes client and open the database (If you don't have enought rights you will see here)
3. when the database is open go in view > agent and it switch automatically to the designer > the database will open (it's a bit long but you can see the current processes - clic on the orange icon at the bottom right and wait)